# How to Load templates from external folder using Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working with spring boot and thymeleaf to generate Documents from html templates.

As the templates continuously changes, i want ti to load templates from an external just to add or remove templates from there instead of redeploy the application.

As a POC, when using /resources folder works fine.

This is the error:

> Error resolving template "voucher", the template might not exist or might
> not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

This is the context:

applycation.yml

```
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    prefix: file:///${PARAMETERS_DIRECTORY_TEMPLATES:/home/app/templates/}
    check-template-location: true
    suffix=: .html
    mode: HTML
    encoding: UTF-8
```

This is my Method:
Where templateName is the template filename and parameters is just a map who has the values to be replaced by the engine.

```
 @Override
public String buildHtmlFromTemplate(String templateName, Map<String, String> parameters) {
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    FileTemplateResolver templateResolver = new FileTemplateResolver ();
    templateResolver.setOrder(templateEngine.getTemplateResolvers().size());
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);

    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

    return templateEngine.process(templateName, this.resolveHtmlTemplateAttributesContext(parameters));
}
```

NOTE:
I removed tha applycation yml thymeleaf configs and implemented next code but the error persists.

```
@Override
public String buildHtmlFromTemplate(String templateName, Map<String, String> parameters) {
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    FileTemplateResolver templateResolver = new FileTemplateResolver ();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/home/skeeter/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
    templateResolver.setOrder(templateEngine.getTemplateResolvers().size());
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);

    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

    return templateEngine.process(templateName, this.resolveHtmlTemplateAttributesContext(parameters));
}
```

Comment: This will resolve your request http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Loading-templates-from-external-source-td4025309.html

Comment: Thanks @SounakSaha i had read this article. 
I think that i'm using the right resolver but can't understan what i'm missing.

Comment: When setting the prefix in Java code for a `FileTemplateResolver`, you use a simple file path - for example, `/path/to/templatesDir/` - without the URL-style use of `file://`. I don't know if the syntax is different just because you are using Spring's `application.yml`. Try commenting out the `prefix` line in the config file, and adding `templateResolver.setPrefix("/path/to/templatesDir/");` in your Java code, as a test.

Comment: @andrewjames i tried moving all configs to the code but the error persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curiously, the issue was solved using this code and the /usr/app/templates created with sudo.
I think it was only a permissions issue

```
.....
@Value("${parameters.directory.templates}")
private String templatesDirectory;  
.....    


@Override
public String buildHtmlFromTemplate(String templateName, Map<String, String> parameters) {
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    FileTemplateResolver templateResolver = new FileTemplateResolver ();
    templateResolver.setPrefix(templatesDirectory);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
    templateResolver.setOrder(templateEngine.getTemplateResolvers().size());
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);

    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

    return templateEngine.process(templateName, this.resolveHtmlTemplateAttributesContext(parameters));
}
```

Comment: i am still facing this issue

Comment: Give us more info please.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using the `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver`, but after I changed it to `FileTemplateResolver` I can use the absolute path and it works fine.

Double check that you have read permissions in the directory where you have the templates.